# Does a Java "reference object" exist?

Tags: java, object, reference

Sometimes I would like to pass an immutable object to a method and change its value inside of the method or I would like the assign another object to the parameter reference (example 1). Or I would like to assign inside of an anonymous inner class another object to a final local variable (example 2). Because all of these cases are not possible, sometimes I use an Atomic(Integer|Long...) class or a list (which is really bad, because a list can contain multiple objects) for this purpose. Alternatively, I could create a class which holds an object and allows changing the object:

```
public class ReferenceExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Reference<String> string = new Reference<>("a");
        // Example 1:
        method(string);

        // Example 2:
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                string.set("c");
            };
        }.start();
    }

    public static void method(Reference<String> string) {
        string.set("b");
    }

    private static class Reference<T> {
        private T value;

        public Reference() {}

        public Reference(T value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public T get() {
            return value;
        }

        public void set(T value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

}
```

I am wondering if such a class does already exists in Java or a common library (e.g. in an apache common project)? If not, are there any other good solutions for these problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've found the main solution, but the other two common approaches are

- `AtomicReference`, which it looks like you've already found
- A single-element array, which acts more or less as a mutable reference

That said, you can usually find ways around the need:

- return the (potentially different) reference from your method
- implement the method inside a class which contains the mutable reference as a field, which is frequently more appropriate anyway

Answer (score 0):

There is no generic and typically used solution in plain java. And it's probably bad practice to use one instead of using javaish specific solutions.

Common solutions :

- let the caller make the assignement :

  `myVal = anObject.aMethod(myVal);`
- provide the enclosing object

  `anObject.aMethod(this);`
- provide a callback which will assign the variable a new value. To to this you usually have to define an interface that your callback implements :

  anObject.aMethod(new MySetter(){
      public void set(int newval) {
          myVal = newval;
       };
   });

It's totally true that java forces you to make more encapsulation sometimes that you'd want. This may seem a good thing or may be seen as one of the reasons java is considered a verbose language.